# No profiling information for SOQL operations (Apex Class in Profile)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, soql, screen-flow, system-permissions

I have a custom aura component was built to have a custom lookup field in it. The custom aura lookup field takes a search query and replicates standard lookup fields dynamic dropdown.  The component works in our `PartialBox` and does not work in our `Fullbox`:

### Summary of Environment Settings

- Environments' are both on preview of `Summer 22'`
- Environments' (Partial vs Fullbox) `Profile` MetaData is identical.
- Environments' `PermissionSet` MetaData is identical.
- Environments' Profiles do have access to the `Apex Class` that is running the query(see below).
- Environments' Profiles/Permission sets have `modify all` on the custom object and its lookup object.
- Environments' `Aura Components` are identical .
- Environments' `Apex Class` and `AuraMethods` are identical

I'm confident there has to be another way to grant access to apex class that is missing. But even running it as a System Admin is displaying the errors in the screen shot.

[image: No Profiling Information]

### Helper.JS

```
getSchools: function (component, event) {
    var action = component.get("c.getAllRecords"),
        searchText = event.getSource().get('v.value'),
        searchTextLength = searchText.length,
        className = event.getSource().get('v.class');
    

    action.setParams({
        searchKeyWord: searchText,
        objectApiName: 'Custom_SalesforceObj__c',
        colums: 'Id, Name '
    });
    action.setStorable();
    action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
        $A.util.removeClass(component.find("mySpinner"), "slds-show");
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
            var data = response.getReturnValue();
            if (data.length == 0) {
                component.set('v.isMessage', false);
                component.set("v.schoolList", []);
                component.set('v.editSchoolList', []);
                component.set("v.Message", 'No Result Found...');

            } else if (data.length > 0) {
                var forOpen;
                if (className.indexOf('editLookup') > -1) {
                    forOpen = component.find("editSearchRes");
                    component.set('v.editSchoolList', data);
                } else {
                    component.set('v.isMessage', false);
                    forOpen = component.find("searchRes");
                    component.set('v.schoolList', data);
                }
                component.set("v.Message", '');
                component.set('v.hideResultClassName', 'slds-show');
            } else {
                component.set('v.editSchoolList', []);
                component.set("v.schoolList", []);
                var forclose = component.find("searchRes");
                $A.util.addClass(forclose, 'slds-is-close');
                $A.util.removeClass(forclose, 'slds-is-open');
                component.set('v.hideResultClassName', 'slds-hide');
            }
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

### ApexClass.getAllRecords() (called From JS)

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static List < sObject > getAllRecords(String searchKeyWord, String objectApiName, String colums) {
        List < sObject > recordList = new List < sObject > ();
        String searchKey = '%' + searchKeyWord + '%';
        if (searchKeyWord != null && searchKeyWord.length() >= 1 ) {
            try {                
                recordList = Database.query('SELECT ' + colums + ' FROM ' + objectApiName + ' WHERE Name LIKE: searchKey LIMIT 25');
                 if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                        throw new DMLException('Records not found');
                    }
            } catch (DMLException ex) {
                AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException('There is a problem in to get details for current user. ' + ex.getMessage());
                e.setMessage('There is a problem in to get details for current user.' + ex.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }
            if (recordList.size() > 0) {
                return recordList;
            }
        }
        return recordList;
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to check your TraceFlag and DebugLevel settings. If you don't ask for profiling, you don't get any profiling.

Comment: I have profiling set to finest when I got these logs.

Comment: Not sure what to say, then. Nothing seems amiss here. Maybe you're looking at the wrong log? I know I do that all the time.

Comment: Is it possible that it's failing because the method is being called on keyup? Meaning too many call outs to server?

Comment: It was the action.setStorable(); method. Do you know why that would cause a problem?

Comment: Actually, that makes sense. It was deprecated in v53.0 or so. Use cacheable=true instead if you want to cache the results.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the issue. Per @sfdcfox.

We had `action.setSTorable()` as part of the call out to the apex method. It's unclear to me the mechanism that was causing this to fail, but the primary reason is that it was deprecated.